# What is the equivalent of C# method groups in Scala?

Tags: c#, scala, functional-programming

In C# there is this very convenient thing called method groups, basically instead of writing:

```
someset.Select((x,y) => DoSomething(x,y))
```

you can write:

```
someset.Select(DoSomething)
```

is there something similar in Scala?

For example:

```
int DoSomething(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int SomethingElse(int x, Func<int,int,int> f)
{
    return x + f(1,2);
}

void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(SomethingElse(5, DoSomething));
}
```

Comment: Weird terminology, we call those things "events".

Comment: `DoSomething` is a method group, because it refers to all overloads of it at the same time. Being able to use a method group like this is called an implicit method group conversion, because it implicitly converts a method group to the required delegate type.

Comment: @Blindy At least in C# the word "event" isn't used for this.

Comment: +1 Interesting question! I don't think this is related to events in either language.

Comment: It is not directly related to events in C#, but it is often used to attach an event handler to an event, for example,

someevent += DoSomething

Comment: That's nothing else than [eta conversion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion). I would expect that from every functional language.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, nor in Scala. I don't know what Blindy is talking about.

Comment: @phg, right. You should post that as answer.

Comment: @phg Not really sure if you can call it that. In C# both a lambda and a method group can be converted to a delegate of the fitting signature. No adding/dropping involved. The JITter is allowed to optimize the indirection out, but you can't rely on that.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Of course that was only meant on an abstract level. What's done at IL level doesn't interest me as functional programmer... The point is that you can always substitute one for another and get the same behavior (unless you do evil low level stuff, maybe).

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sure, overload resolving complicates things. But that's more like syntactic sugar. Probably there's a weird typed lambda calculus which includes even that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In scala we call that a function ;-). `(x,y) => DoSomething(x,y)` is an anonymous function or closure, but you can pass any function that matches the signature of the method/function you are calling, in this case `map`. So for example in scala you can simply write

```
List(1,2,3,4).foreach(println)
```

or

```
case class Foo(x: Int)
List(1,2,3,4).map(Foo) // here Foo.apply(_) will be called
```

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting i have come to the conclusion that it kind of works the same way in Scala as in C# (not sure if it is actually the same though...)

This is what I was trying to achieve (playing around with Play! so Scala is new to me, not sure why this didn't work in my views, but it works fine when I try it in the interpreter)

```
def DoStuff(a: Int, b : Int) = a + b

def SomethingElse(x: Int, f (a : Int, b: Int) => Int)) = f(1,2) + x

SomethingElse(5, DoStuff)    
res1: Int = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually simulate the behavior of method groups with partial functions. However, it's probably not a recommended approach, as you force any type errors to occur at runtime, as well as incur some cost to determine which overload to call. However, does this code do what you want?

```
object MethodGroup extends App {
   //The return type of "String" was chosen here for illustration
   //purposes only. Could be any type.
   val DoSomething: Any => String = {
        case () => "Do something was called with no args"
        case (x: Int) => "Do something was called with " + x
        case (x: Int, y: Int) => "Do something was called with " + (x, y)
    }

    //Prints "Do something was called with no args"
    println(DoSomething())

    //Prints "Do something was called with 10"
    println(DoSomething(10))

    //Prints "Do something was called with (10, -7)"
    println(DoSomething(10,-7))

    val x = Set((), 13, (20, 9232))
    //Prints the following... (may be in a different order for you)
    //Do something was called with no args
    //Do something was called with 13
    //Do something was called with (20, 9232)
    x.map(DoSomething).foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: Again, not that the above is recommended, but you could probably generate that boilerplate with a macro in 2.10, meaning that such a "MethodGroup" would be able to be defined in a more traditional method.

Comment: It won't actually work for functions of different arity. If you expect a _tuple_, ok, it works. But if you expect a `Function2`, it won't.